# Getting char index of a textbox text

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, autocomplete, mask

Im trying to create a custom mask for my jquery autocomplete control.

I have a textbox whose default text is something like this `"___-__.__._"`

For example when a user enters <kbd>a</kbd> when cursor is after "-" I want to change the text to

`"___-a_.__._"` by replacing "_" with user pressed key <kbd>a</kbd>

any ideas?

Comment: Can you use four different, smaller text fields, instead of one long one?

Comment: have you tried something? In the mean time check out this pluginm it does exactly that: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: i cant use more than 1 textfield since its a autocomplete field

Comment: i tried that plugin but it stops autocomplete from working

Comment: yeah but since you seam to have no clue how to do it you could read its source and ask more specific questions...